# QRcode decoder on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, qr-code, zxing, javax.imageio

I am trying to write a Google App Engine (GAE) Java app to decode QRcodes. Users of my app will send an email to the app with an image containing a QRcode which they want to decode and my GAE app would send a reply with the decoded info. I was planning to use [zxing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) for this.

Currently I am able to extract the image which came as an attachment in the email. But now to use zxing I need imageIO and BufferedImage classes, which are not part of GAE whitelist. So I am stuck. Can somebody please help me figure out how I can decode a QRcode, with or without zxing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides their own API for [working with images on GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/package-summary).  You will need to use this API instead of `javax.imageio.*`.  Or rather, since it's your library that makes use of these classes, you'll have to modify the library's source code to work with the GAE classes (or switch to a different library, or write your own).  That may be a fairly sizeable job, depending upon how heavily the library relies upon `javax.imageio.*`.

Edit:  Maybe you can refactor your code to use zxing's [web-based decoder](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx)?  That might be simpler than trying to modify their library to use the GAE image API.

Comment: Yes, if this API will give back the image data in ARGB format (I can't tell if the method that returns `byte[]` does this) then it's easy to just change a few lines to use `RGBLuminanceSource`.

Comment: @SeanOwen & aroth: Thanks guys! As I mentioned before that I am sending the image as an email attachment. So when I extract the image from the MimeMessage, I get it as base64 encoded format. I am having trouble in converting the base64 encoded data into actual image(PNG or JPG) or ARGB format. Can you guys please help: I have raised a [question for this here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375806/decoding-base64-image-received-as-email-on-google-app-engine)